# Phabricator git clone error 403

Tags: git, docker, phabricator

I have created a git repositry in phabricator from diffusion-> active repository -> new repository with hosting server over http read/write enable
After have try to clone this new repositry on my computer, I submit username and password and got error 403 :

> fatal: unable to access
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8081/diffusion/TESTMAU/mau-test.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

I use it with this docker : https://github.com/yesnault/docker-phabricator

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem solved :
To use git from phabricator in http, we need to use VCS password not the account password. And it's works !

Comment: Yup, as a general rule, "403" means "access denied", or more specifically "your username or password is wrong" (in most cases).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to feedback.

Comment: Set it in `User/Settings/Authentication/VCS password`